# Accessing a webservice on my localhost

Tags: web-services, wsdl, localhost

I've a running WebService published on `"http://localhost:8080/FreeMeteoWS/FreeMeteoWS?WSDL"`. I want to access this webservice from a device on the same network...what address should I put in order to retrieve the wsdl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that port i.e. 8080 is open for incoming connections on your computer you'd only need to find your local ip-address, this is done in different manners on different operating systems. When you have obtained local ip-address switch localhost out in favor for that ip-address.